# How to return dict from within a function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a dict that should have multiple keys and values however when doing it inside a function it's only returning the first key, value.

I think this is because I'm using `return` in the wrong place but I'm unsure how to make it work correctly.

I have this list that i'm trying to convert into a dict within a function

```
In [876]: cable_map
Out[876]: ['SYD_A_1234 <> Outlet1', 'SYD_B_4567 <> Outlet2', 'MELB_A_1111 <> Outlet1']
```

here is the function

```
In [880]: def make_map():
     ...:     mymap = {}
     ...:     for line in cable_map:
     ...:         if re.search("SYD", line.split(' <> ',1)[0]):
     ...:             mymap.update({line.split(' <> ',1)[0]:line.split(' <> ',1)[1]})
     ...:             return mymap
     ...:
     ...:     return {}
     ...:

In [882]: cable_map = make_map()

In [883]: cable_map
Out[883]: {'SYD_A_1234': 'Outlet1'}
```

As you can see it's only putting the first key, value in the dict.  If i run this same code outside of a function it works as expected:

```
In [891]: mymap = {}
     ...: for line in cable_map:
     ...:     if re.search("SYD", line.split(' <> ',1)[0]):
     ...:         mymap.update({line.split(' <> ',1)[0]:line.split(' <> ',1)[1]})
     ...:
     ...:

In [892]: mymap
Out[892]: {'SYD_A_1234': 'Outlet1', 'SYD_B_4567': 'Outlet2'}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are returning `mymap` too soon, at the end of the first iteration. Return it *after* the loop as completed.

Comment: You returning `mymap` from if. it should be outside loop

Comment: Ah-ha... silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `return` statement causes your function to exit on the first iteration of the loop, whereas outside the function the loop runs through all the `line`s in `cable_map`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_cable_map = ['SYD_A_1234 <> Outlet1', 'SYD_B_4567 <> Outlet2', 'MELB_A_1111 <> Outlet1']    
def make_map(cable_map):
    mymap = {}
    for line in cable_map:
        if re.search("SYD", line.split(' <> ', 1)[0]):
            mymap.update({line.split(' <> ', 1)[0]: line.split(' <> ', 1)[1]})
    return mymap

print(make_map(my_cable_map))
```

Comment: Thanks... this is what i ended up with.

Comment: what is the purpose of putting `cable_map` here `def make_map(cable_map):`. i was not able to make it work with that code.

Comment: cable_map is your variable
when you call this function you can pass your variable

Answer (score 0):

Working code now:

```
In [919]: def make_map():
     ...:     mymap = {}
     ...:     for line in cable_map:
     ...:         if re.search("SYD", line.split(' <> ',1)[0]):
     ...:             mymap.update({line.split(' <> ',1)[0]:line.split(' <> ',1)[1]})
     ...:     return mymap
     ...:

In [920]: cable_map = make_map()

In [921]: cable_map
Out[921]: {'SYD_A_1234': 'Outlet1', 'SYD_B_4567': 'Outlet2'}
```